# Highstock / Highcharts - Flag linecolor masking line below it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my image below you see two lines, both green, at the top.

[image]

The higher green line has a flag (that is what you see to the left).

The lower green line, is usually red.

After playing around for hours to determine what is making the lower line green, I discovered only changing `lineColor` on the flag of the higher green line above it, did this series change from red to green.

In the navigator below, you can see the bottom line is actually red. Underneath it, is a long green block - I don't understand where this is from.

Here is an example of changing the lineColor of the flag, and the line below changes.. you'll notice what looks like the big green mask in the navigator is still there.
[image]

Lastly, this is the same chart on another page - no problems at all, the red line is red.
[image]

The top line's flag looks like:

```
{
     allowOverlapX: true,
     showInLegend: false,
     enableMouseTracking: false,
     type: 'flags',
     name: `${id}-flags`,
     onSeries: id,
     data: [{ title: 'Flag text', x: Date }],
     shape: 'flag',
     fillColor: 'green',
     style: {
         fontSize: 10,
         fontWeight: 500,
         color: '#FFFFFF',
         paddingBottom: 2
     },
     yAxis: 0,
     lineColor: flagColor[classification], //Responsible for overriding the line from red to green.
     lineWidth: 1,
     height: 12,
     y: -45,
     }
```

The higher and lower lines look something like this:

```
type: 'line',
startX,
endX,
id,
enableMouseTracking: true,
name: id,
showInLegend: false,
showInNavigator: true,
color: stroke,
lineWidth: strokeWidth,
marker: { enabled: false },
yAxis: 0,
data: [[startX, pPrice], [endX, price]],
```

I should also note that sometimes this doesn't happen, I just can't figure out what would cause this.

Has anyone run into something like this before?

Comment: don't know much of highcharts, but  `flagColor[classification]` seems to come from you. Are you sure you are not mutating `flagColor` object somewhere upstream?

Comment: I don't think so, because as you can see in the images, when I hard code the value of lineColor to blue - it has different behavior, sometimes its normal, and sometimes it seems to mask a totally different line.

Comment: You are in truth confirming what I'm suspecting, the fact that the problem disappears once you hardcode lineColor only makes me suspect flagColor object more. I believe this is some sort of object you are using within your script, as it passed by reference, it's very likely you are changing it sometimes. Modify the json object and do this: `lineColor: (function(color){console.log(color);return color;}(flagColor[classification]))`  . Observe the logs to see what the color is.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin sorry - to be clear, the problem does not go away when I hard code it. As you can see in the middle image above, it is hard coded blue, and another line also turns blue for no reason at all. The same chart, with the hard coded line on a different page, does not turn the red line blue (the bottom image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix this, and if anyone ever stumbles upon it - here is the solution.

I'm not sure sure why this only happens sometimes, but it seems like lineColor should also be defined on the line series itself (as opposed to only color).